# unable to receive form info

Tags: php, forms

I am creating an email form using dreamweaver and I wrote just some codes in PHP to gather form info and send it to an email. Everything works just fine but I have a big problem. In fact I want to user a right-to-left language like Persian or Arabic for my form. When I fill in the form with English words, in my email I receive good stuff but when I type in something if Arabic, I receive something like Ù†Ø§Ù… Ø®Ø§Ù†ÙˆØ§Ø¯Ú¯ÛŒ in my email:
Here comes my PHP code:

```
<?php

$_POST['emailAddress'] = "info@behzadmoradi.com";
$to = "info@behzadmoradi.com";
$subject = "نظر در مورد سکان آکادمی";
$message .= "نام ".$_POST['name'] . "\n";
$message .= "نام خانوادگی ".$_POST['lastName'] . "\n";
$message .= "آدرس ایمیل ".$_POST['email']  ."\n";
$message .= "نوع درخواست ".$_POST['request'] . "\n";
$message .= "متن درخواست ".$_POST['requestText'] . "\n";

mail($to, $subject, $body, $message);

header ( "Location: commentThankYouPage.php ");

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
$headers = 'Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8' . "\r\n";
mail($to, $subject, $message,$headers);// 3rd param is message or body check this param
```

Read this http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

Also you can use [phpmailer library](https://github.com/Synchro/PHPMailer)

Comment: <?php
$_POST['emailAddress'] = "info@behzadmoradi.com";
$to = "info@behzadmoradi.com";
$subject = "نظر در مورد سکان آکادمی";
$message .= "نام ".$_POST['name'] . "\n";
$message .= "نام خانوادگی ".$_POST['lastName'] . "\n";
$message .= "آدرس ایمیل ".$_POST['email']  ."\n";
$message .= "نوع درخواست ".$_POST['request'] . "\n";
$message .= "متن درخواست ".$_POST['requestText'] . "\n";

mail($to, $subject, $body, $message);

header ( "Location: commentThankYouPage.php ");

?>